# Html,css,Javascript Imgage Gallary pagination with Next and Previous Buttons Only

Tags: javascript, html, css

HI friends I need a Image Gallary pagination with only two button NEXT and Previous

Both buttons are with text[Next/PREV] only Single Image Display and Should be change on next/prev click...Can any one help me how can i create..

Comment: show us what code you have so far

Comment: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

This is a great one follow the guide

Comment: var AHS = function () { };

AHS.prototype.sendPost = function (url, data, callback, antiForgeryToken, async)

Comment: var IsAsync = true;if (async == false) {IsAsync = false;}$.ajax({url: url,type: 'POST',async: IsAsync,data: data,headers: {"RequestVerificationToken": antiForgeryToken},error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {callback.failure(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);},success: function (data, textStatus) {callback.success(data, textStatus);}});

Comment: var aHS = new AHS();aHS.sendPost('test/test', {  }, callback = {success: function (r, tS) {$('#dv').empty();$('#dv').html(r)},failure: function (XHR, tS, errorThrown) {var r = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);WriteError(XHR.status, r.IsAjaxError);}}, GT());

Comment: function GT() {return $("input[name=_RequestVerificationToken]").val();}